# How to run a ffmpeg code on a GPU?

Tags: video, graphics-card, ffmpeg, gpu

we have written a short code in C code to read a video file, using common libraries as libavcodec, libavformat etc.. The code is running smoothly but only using the CPU resources. We'd need to run the code on the GPU (Nvidia GeForce 940MX and 1080Ti). Is there a way to force the code to be run on the GPU?
While using the command line (e.g., “ffmpeg -hwaccel cuvid -i vid.mp4 out.avi”) things are fine, we are not able to have it working on the GPU from the source code. 
We are working with Ubuntu 18.04, and ffmpeg correctly compiled with CUDA 9.2
Thanks in advance for your help!